# Ignore a letter in isPalindrome() method - Java

Tags: java, oop, palindrome

I am wondering how the following method could be modified to ignore a certain letter and have it as a wildcard when checking if a string is a palindrome...

example: "wows", in this case the method should return false but

"pat" , the 't' can be a wildcard (considered as a p) and therefore it returns true

"job" , again the b can be a wildcard and considered as a j, therefore method returns true.

this is what i have so far, i have a seperate method ignoring special characters and spaces so  that does not need to be considered in this post.

```
private static boolean checkPalindrome2(String word) {
    if(word.length() < 2) { 
        return true;  
    }
    char first  = word.charAt(0);
    char last   = word.charAt(word.length()-1);
    if(first != last) { 
        return false; 
    }
    else { 
        return checkPalindrome2(word.substring(1,word.length()-1));
    }
}
```

this is my test class,

```
public class testPalindromes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //if (Palindromes.isPalindrome("a") == true) {
        //  System.out.println("true");
        //} else {
        //  System.out.println("false");
        //}

        // block above is the same as this
        // isPalindrome already returns true or false, 
        // and true and false can be printed as strings
        System.out.println(isPalindrome("a"));

        if (Palindromes.isPalindrome("cat") == true) {
            System.out.println("true");
        } else {
            System.out.println("false");
        }
        if (Palindromes.isPalindrome("w o    w") == true) {
            System.out.println("true");
        } else {
            System.out.println("false");
        }
        if (Palindromes.isPalindrome("   a  ") == true) {
            System.out.println("true");
        } else {
            System.out.println("false");
        }
        if (Palindromes.isPalindrome("mom!") == true) {
            System.out.println("true");

        if (Palindromes.isPalindrome2("cat")==true){
            System.out.print("true");
        } else {
            System.out.println("false");
            }

        }

    }

}
```

isPalindromes2 is a method calling the checkPalindrome2 method above, the last case in my test class (word cat) should return true because the t will be the wildcard letter (wildcard again as stated above, replaced with c making cat, cac which is a palindrome)

thanks in advance for all help / input!!!!
ps, i purposely implemented a recursive method.

Answer (score 2):

Just add extra conditions to your base case:

```
// both first and last have to NOT be the special character
// and first has to not equal last for this to return false
if(first != special && last != special && first != last)
    return false; 
else
    return checkPalindrome(word.substring(1,word.length()-1));
```

Comment: @choloboy7 Nevermind, I see that you take car of the odd case already. I missed it because I only copied part of your code over.

Comment: what would be the appropriate way to declare special? and would you mind explaining how this works? I dont fully understand how these conditions will take a single char as a wildcard :S please and thanks :)

Comment: Well you could pass it to the palindrome function itself: `private static boolean checkPalindrome(String word, char special)`, or you could define it globally in your class `private char special = '<char>';`

Comment: sorry i meant how would i initialize it****

Comment: ive tried testing it for the word "cat" but it everything ive tried ends up being false, when considering the specifications i need of the method the "t" is the wildcard and should be considered as a c, thus making cat true

Comment: @choloboy7 You initialize a character by declaring it explicitly, it is a primitive type. `char c = 'c';` You could pass a `char` to the method above by calling `checkPalindrome("cat", 'c');`

Comment: to avoid that (i have a specific test class) could this work, in the if condition just make last equal first if different or make first equal last if different?

Comment: @choloboy7 I am kind of confused by what you are asking, can you post your test file in your question so I can see it ?

Comment: @choloboy7 How is the wildcard decided? Also I took the liberty of simplifying one of your expressions, you have a lot of extra unneeded code.

Comment: essentially, if there is one letter preventing a word from being a palindrome, it is to be replaced with the appropriate letter making the word a palindrome. No more than one letter though

Comment: @choloboy7 If the wildcard can be anywhere you are going to have to look at the state of the palindrome, once the base condition fails, then decide from there if it was off by one letter.